# Openstack Nova - attribute error when attempting to map cell0

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

Following the docs ([OpenStack](https://docs.openstack.org/install-guide/index.html), [Nova](https://docs.openstack.org/nova/train/install/controller-install-rdo.html#install-and-configure-components)) while doing a small manual install of OpenStack Train on CentOS7.  Everything is going relatively smoothly until attempting to map cell0.

Executing:
`su -s /bin/sh -c "nova-manage cell_v2 map_cell0" nova`

Yields:

```
An error has occurred:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/cmd/manage.py", line 2712, in main
    ret = fn(*fn_args, **fn_kwargs)
  File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/cmd/manage.py", line 1067, in map_cell0
    self._map_cell0(database_connection=database_connection)
  File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/cmd/manage.py", line 1092, in _map_cell0
    dbc = database_connection or cell0_default_connection()
  File "/opt/stack/nova/nova/cmd/manage.py", line 1089, in cell0_default_connection
    url.database = url.database + '_cell0' AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Have gone through the config files a number of times and everything seems fine and haven't run into this issue when testing with VMs.  Initially thought there was an issue connecting to the database but I'm able to create new cells which uses the same database connection.  Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: An attribute error may indicate that you installed incompatible software versions.

Comment: Thanks, will look into this later today.